# How to get Started with Ember on windows using npm?

Tags: node.js, ember.js, web-applications, dependencies

```
C:\Users\andri>cd ember-cli
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.

C:\Users\andri>npm install -g bower
npm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.2: ...psst! Your project can stop working at any moment because its dependencies can change. Prevent this by migrating to Yarn: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/
C:\Users\andri\AppData\Roaming\npm\bower -> C:\Users\andri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\bin\bower
+ bower@1.8.2

added 1 package in 23.177s

C:\Users\andri>ember new testapp-app
installing app
  create .editorconfig
  create .ember-cli
  create .eslintrc.js
  create .travis.yml
  create .watchmanconfig
  create README.md
  create app\app.js
  create app\components\.gitkeep
  create app\controllers\.gitkeep
  create app\helpers\.gitkeep
  create app\index.html
  create app\models\.gitkeep
  create app\resolver.js
  create app\router.js
  create app\routes\.gitkeep
  create app\styles\app.css
  create app\templates\application.hbs
npm: Installed dependencies
Successfully initialized git.s

C:\Users\andri>ember server
node_modules appears empty, you may need to run `npm install`


C:\Users\andri>bower install
bower                           ENOENT No bower.json present

C:\Users\andri>ember server
node_modules appears empty, you may need to run `npm install`
```

I am trying to install ember and keep getting errors. Does anybody understand what I am doing wrong? I am watching a youtube tutorial and I follow the steps that are on the video, still it doesnt work, in fact I get totally different results  :/ I have also installed git.. Could somebody explain to me what is happening here? I am very new to all these and therefore I cannot spot the mistakes. Thank you in advance

Comment: next time specify the environment on which you are working also.

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows Users:::**

Install Node js for windows and then install npm package for it and if you have done that.

You can install ember from npm.

Install Ember using npm:

```
npm install -g ember-cli@3.0
```

To verify that your installation was successful, run:

```
ember -v
```

If a version number is shown, you're ready to go.

see the link below for more details...
https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/getting-started/

Comment: It's clear from the context provided that the user already has ember-cli installed.

Answer (score 0):

looking your prompt, to start a ember server, just go to your ember app folder (cd\testapp-app) and use ember serve or ember s

Answer (score 0):

Your last error there is telling you what's missing.

**`node_modules appears empty, you may need to run npm install`**

Running `npm install` in the project folder and then running `ember server` should get you up and running. The default URL is http://localhost:4200 when ember-cli has spun up the server.